# Oracle Apex 22.21 - REST data source - nested JSON array - discovery

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to get APEX Rest Data Source to parse my JSON which has a nested array. I've read that JSON nested arrays are not supported but there must be a way.

I have a REST API that returns data via JSON as per below. On Apex, I've created a REST data source following the tutorial on this Oracle blog [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/synchronize-data-from-rest-services-to-local-table-with-no-code-at-all)

However, Auto-Discovery does not 'discover' the nested array. It only returns the root level data.

```
[ {
  "order_number": "so1223",
  "order_date": "2022-07-01",
  "full_name": "Carny Coulter",
  "email": "ccoulter2@ovh.net",
  "credit_card": "3545556133694494",
  "city": "Myhiya",
  "state": "CA",
  "zip_code": "12345",
  "lines": [
    {
      "product": "Beans - Fava, Canned",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 1.99
    },
    {
      "product": "Edible Flower - Mixed",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 1.50
    }
  ]
},
{
  "order_number": "so2244",
  "order_date": "2022-12-28",
  "full_name": "Liam Shawcross",
  "email": "lshawcross5@exblog.jp",
  "credit_card": "6331104669953298",
  "city": "Humaitá",
  "state": "NY",
  "zip_code": "98670",
  "lines": [
    {
      "order_id": 5,
      "product": "Beans - Green",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 4.33
    },
    {
      "order_id": 1,
      "product": "Grapefruit - Pink",
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": 5.00
    }
  ]
},
]
```

So in the JSON above, it only 'discovers' order_numbers up to zip_code. The 'lines' array with attributes order_id, product, quantity, & price do not get 'discovered'.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68942406/how-to-set-up-a-data-profile-for-apex-21-1-rest-data-source-with-no-row-selector) in which Carsten instructs to create the Rest Data Source manually. I've tried changing the *Row Selector* to "." (a dot) and leaving it blank. That still returns the root level data.

[image: Row Selector]

Changing the *Row Selector* to 'lines' returns only 1 array for each  'lines'

[image]

So in the JSON example above, it would only 'discover':

```
    {
      "product": "Beans - Fava, Canned",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 1.99
    }
    {
      "order_id": 5,
      "product": "Beans - Green",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 4.33
    }
```

and not the complete array..

[image]

**This is how the Data Profile is set up when creating Data Source manually.**

There's [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909288/apex-rest-data-source-does-not-recognize-all-columns) with a similar situation so I followed some steps such as selecting the data type for 'lines' as JSON Document. I feel I've tried almost every selector & data type. But obviously not enough.

[image]

The docs are not very helpful on this subject and it's been difficult finding links on Google, Oracle Blogs, or SO.

My end goal would be to have two tables as below auto synchronizing from the API.

```
orders
    id pk
    order_number num
    order_date date
    full_name vc(200)
    email vc(200)
    credit_card num
    city vc(200)
    state vc(200)
    zip_code num

    lines
        order_id /fk orders
        product vc(200)
        quantity num
        price num

view orders_view orders lines
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're correctly stating, REST Data Sources do not support nested arrays - a REST Source can only "extract" one flat table from the JSON response. In your example, the JSON as such is an array ("orders"). The **Row Selector** in the **Data Profile** would thus be "`.`" (to select the "root node").

That gives you all the order attributes, but discovery would skip the `lines` array. However, you can manually add a column to the Data Profile, of the JSON Document data type, and using lines as the selector.

As a result, you'd still get a flat table from the REST Data Source, but that table contains a `LINES` column, which contains the "JSON Fragment" for the order line items. You could then synchronize the REST Source to a local table ("**REST Synchronization**"), then you can use some custom code to extract the JSON fragments to a `ORDER_LINES` child table.

Does that help?

Comment: Hey Carsten, you're a legend. Your instructions worked exactly how I wanted. Thank you.  I've continued my question on another thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192510/oracle-apex-rest-data-source-nested-json-array-sync-two-tables-where-to  Please take a look and advise. Your support is much appreciated.. not only by me.. Cheers!