# Oracle Apex 22.21 - REST data source - nested JSON array - sync two tables by trigger - PLSQL error question

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

This question is a follow up to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192510/oracle-apex-rest-data-source-nested-json-array-sync-two-tables-where-to).

I've actually recreated the tables from the previous question. The updated JSON response can be found at the bottom of this question.

`ORDERS_LOCAL` table

[image: ORDERS_LOCAL table]

`ORDERS_LOCAL` table data. `ORDER_ITEMS` column is the JSON array that I need to extract into `ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL` table.

[image: ORDERS_LOCAL table data]

`ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL` table. `LINE_ID` column should be created automatically. `ORDER_ID` column is a foreign key to `ORDERS_LOCAL` table. `PRODUCT_ID` column is a foreign key to `PRODUCTS` table. `LINE_NUMBER` is just the order line number (line 1 = product 1, price, qty | line 2 = product 2, price, qty etc..) I believe it's called a `sequence` type?

[image: ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL table]

`PRODUCTS` table

[image: PRODUCTS TABLE]

`PRODUCTS` table data

[image: PRODUCTS Table Data]

Per Carsten's answer, I've created a new trigger for the `ORDERS` table from the **Object Browser**.

[image: Create Trigger from Object Brower]

I've then entered Carsten's PLSQL code from the previous question. He did mention that it was pseudo-code. So I tried to update it..

```
create or replace trigger "TR_MAINTAIN_LINES"
AFTER
insert or update or delete on "ORDERS_LOCAL"
for each row
begin
    if inserting then
        insert into ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL ( line_id, order_id, line_number, product_id, quantity, price) 
        ( select :new.id,
                 seq_lines.nextval,
                 j.line_number,
                 j.product_id,
                 j.quantity,
                 j.price
            from json_table( 
                     :new.order_items,
                     '$[*]' columns (
                         line_number for ordinality,
                         product_id  number path '$.product_id',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    number        path '$.price' ) ) );
    elsif deleting then
        delete ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
        where order_id = :old.id;
    elsif updating then
        delete ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
        where order_id = :old.id;
        -- 
        -- handle the update case here.
        -- I would simply delete and re-insert LINES rows.
    end if;
end;
```

**I am receiving the following errors**

```
Compilation failed, line 4 (08:38:57) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ID'Compilation failed, line 19 (08:38:57) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.ID'Compilation failed, line 22 (08:38:57) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.ID'
```

I believe this is due to missing columns in the trigger code but I'm not sure.

I am new to PLSQL and parsing the JSON is kind of confusing.. especially below. Please see my comments.

```
    if inserting then
        insert into ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL ( line_id, order_id, line_number, product_id, quantity, price) 
        ( select :new.id,                  -- is this new id for `line_id`
                 order_id                  -- how to insert order_id foreign key
                 seq_lines.nextval,        -- not sure what this is for?
                 j.line_number,            -- I changed 'lines' to 'order_items' so should this be seq_order_items.nextval, ?
                 j.product_id,             
                 j.quantity,
                 j.price
            from json_table( 
                     :new.order_items,           -- I changed 'lines' to 'order_items' so I changed this from :new.lines,
                     '$[*]' columns (            -- Would I include 'line_id' and 'order_id' in here as well?
                         line_number for ordinality,
                         product_id  number path '$.product_id',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    number        path '$.price' ) ) );
```

Updated JSON response

```
[
{
    "order_id": "HO9b6-ahMY-B2i9",
    "order_number": 34795,
    "order_date": "2022-11-02",
    "store_id": 2,
    "full_name": "Ronda Perfitt",
    "email": "rperfitt1@microsoft.com",
    "city": "Fresno",
    "state": "California",
    "zip_code": "93762",
    "credit_card": "5108758574719798",
    "order_items": [
      {
        "line_number": 1,
        "product_id": 2,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 3418.85
      },
      {
        "line_number": 2,
        "product_id": 7,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 4070.12
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    "order_id": "RFvUC-sN8Y-icJP",
    "order_number": 62835,
    "order_date": "2022-10-09",
    "store_id": 1,
    "full_name": "Wash Rosenfelt",
    "email": "wrosenfelt3@wisc.edu",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "state": "Illinois",
    "zip_code": "60646",
    "credit_card": "5048372443777103",
    "order_items": [
      {
        "line_number": 1,
        "product_id": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 3349.05
      },
      {
        "line_number": 2,
        "product_id": 3,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 4241.29
      },
      {
        "line_number": 3,
        "product_id": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 3560.03
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I apologize for making this confusing. I really want to learn how to do this right. Your support is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the trigger code, the :old and :new prefixes reference the row of your table, before and after the trigger operation. So ...

- In the UPDATING case, `:old.{column-name}` references the value of a table column column *before* the update, `:new.{column-name}` references the value *after* the update.
- In the INSERTING case, there is no `:old.{column-name}` (thus that would be NULL); `:new.{column-name}` references the inserted value.
- And in the DELETING case, there is no `:new.{column-name}` value; only `:old.{column-name}` is available.

You see the compiler error, as my trigger pseudo-code contained :new.id, but your table does not have a column named `ID`; it's `ORDER_ID` in your case. So you need to adjust that code accordingly.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-E76C8044-6942-4573-B7DB-3502FB96CF6F

Comment: Hi Carsten, thank you for your help on this. The Apex community really appreciates your support. I have another follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75207676/oracle-apex-rest-data-source-extract-a-nested-json-array-trigger-two-table Thank you very much

Comment: Hi Carsten, I ran into an error on the `DELETE` case. Would really appreciate it if you could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350157/oracle-apex-rest-data-source-nested-json-array-trigger-two-tables-delete Thank you