# Oracle Apex - REST data source - extract a nested JSON array - trigger two tables - PLSQL error question

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

This question is a follow up to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75199190/oracle-apex-22-21-rest-data-source-nested-json-array-sync-two-tables-by-tr/75200476#75200476).

I've followed Carsten's instructions on the previous question. I am now receiving a new error.

```
Compilation failed, line 9 (08:51:36) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "J"."PRICE": invalid identifierCompilation failed, line 3 (08:51:36) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Trigger

```
create or replace trigger "TR_MAINTAIN_LINES"
AFTER
insert or update or delete on "ORDERS_LOCAL"
for each row
begin
    if inserting then
        insert into ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL ( order_id, line_id, line_number, product_id, quantity, price) 
        ( select :new.order_id,
                 seq_line_id.nextval,
                 j.line_number,
                 j.product_id,
                 j.quantity,
                 j.price
            from json_table( 
                     :new.order_items,
                     '$[*]' columns (
                         line_id for ordinality,
                         line_number number path '$.line_number',
                         product_id  number path '$.product_id',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    number        path '$.price' ) ) );
    elsif deleting then
        delete ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
        where order_id = :old.order_id;
    elsif updating then
        delete ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
        where order_id = :old.order_id;
        -- 
        -- handle the update case here.
        -- I would simply delete and re-insert LINES rows.
    end if;
end;
```

**What I need help figuring out**

- The `order_id` column in `ORDER_ITEMS` table should be a foreign key to the `ORDERS` table referring to the `order_id`. That way each 'order line item' can be traced back to the `order_id`. Is `:new.order_id` correct in this case?

```
        insert into ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL ( order_id, line_id, line_number, product_id, quantity, price) 
        ( select :new.order_id,
                 seq_line_id.nextval,
```

- The `line_id` column in `ORDER_ITEMS` table should be automatically assigned based on the next value (ex: `line_id`:98, `line_id`:99, `line_id`:100) `line_id` is not in the JSON response. Is `seq_line_id.nextval,` correct in this case?
- I am not sure what the `'j'` is referring to. (`j.quantity`, `j.price`)

```
            from json_table( 
                     :new.order_items,
                     '$[*]' columns (
                         line_id for ordinality,
                         line_number number path '$.line_number',
                         product_id  number path '$.product_id',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    number        path '$.price' ) ) );
```

- Does `:new.order_items` grab the `order_items` from the JSON array?
- `'$[*]' columns` = `$`– Start with the current object. `[]` – Look inside an array
- Would I include `order_id` in here as well?

```
JSON RESPONSE
{
    "order_id": "HO9b6-ahMY-B2i9",
    "order_number": 34795,
    "order_date": "2022-11-02",
    "store_id": 2,
    "full_name": "Ronda Perfitt",
    "email": "rperfitt1@microsoft.com",
    "city": "Fresno",
    "state": "California",
    "zip_code": "93762",
    "credit_card": "5108758574719798",
    "order_items": [
      {
        "line_number": 1,
        "product_id": 2,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 3418.85
      },
      {
        "line_number": 2,
        "product_id": 7,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 4070.12
      }
    ]
  },
```

I've found a few resources for the `json_table` function online but I'm having difficulty finding one that's within a trigger function similar to Carsten's code. Your help explaining this would be much appreciated.

-----------UPDATE---------

`ORDERS_LOCAL` Table

[image: ORDERS_LOCAL Table]

`ORDERS_LOCAL` Table data

[image: ORDERS_LOCAL Table data]

`ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL` Table

[image: ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL Table]

- `LINE_ID` column to be automatically created
- `ORDER_ID` column foreign key to `ORDERS_LOCAL` table
- `PRODUCT_ID` column foreign key to `PRODUCTS` table

Comment: Could you show the data in the order_items column ? First try to get the data in sql, once that works move it into the trigger. Writing the trigger immediately without knowing the exact sql can be a challenge.

Comment: Hi Koen, thanks for your response. This is a follow up question to another question that I had [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75199190/oracle-apex-22-21-rest-data-source-nested-json-array-sync-two-tables-by-tr/75200476#75200476). The `order_items` column can be found on the `ORDERS` table. The JSON response will show it as well. I'm able to parse the JSON using `JSON_TABLES` SQL function but I'm not sure how to incorporate that with the trigger. Also, not sure how to create a `line_id` automatically and reference the `order_id` fk to the `ORDER_ITEMS` table. Your help's appreciated

Comment: I understand the question. Please post a sample record of ORDERS_LOCAL, if I have that I can give it a try. Without the actual data in the column orders_item it's a guess.

Comment: Hi Koen, I've updated the post to show the tables and data. Thank you. I need all the Apex expert help I can get

Comment: Carsten pointed you in the right direction. I commented on your comment to his answer.

Comment: Hi Koen, I really appreciate your help on this! This is now working as expected! Thank you so much. I now know what to do in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON_TABLE expression in the FROM clause is missing the alias. The select list uses the "j" prefix for the columns from the JSON_TABLE expression, but the JSON_TABLE is not aliased ...

You might change as follows (note the additional "j" in the last line)

```
            from json_table( 
                     :new.order_items,
                     '$[*]' columns (
                         line_id for ordinality,
                         line_number number path '$.line_number',
                         product_id  number path '$.product_id',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    number        path '$.price' ) ) j );
```

Comment: Hi Carsten, I've added the "j" prefix but I am now receiving another error. `Compilation failed, line 5 (11:28:24) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not existCompilation failed, line 3 (11:28:24) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`

Comment: Error indicates that sequence ```seq_line_id``` does not exist. Create it using ```CREATE SEQUENCE seq_line_id;```

Comment: Hi Carsten, I really appreciate your help and support over the past few days taking time out of your day to answer my questions. You've been extremely helpful. I hope others can receive value from my questions as well. I'm glad to know there's a community of experts willing to help out noobs in Apex.. I now know what to do in the future. However, I may need your help again in the future and will be looking forward to your guidance once again~ You are a lifesaver!

Comment: Carsten and Koen, I actually have another question in regards to the `updating` function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75219903/oracle-apex-rest-data-source-nested-json-array-trigger-two-tables-update Please advise. Thank you very much.