# Oracle Apex - how to calculate the sum of prices matching order id on one table and insert to another table

Tags: oracle-apex

This question is a follow-up to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75219903/oracle-apex-rest-data-source-nested-json-array-trigger-two-tables-update).

This is for an e-commerce platform to show the end-user sales reports. I have a table `ORDERS` and a table `ORDER_ITEMS`. The data is received through a REST API as a JSON response. The JSON is synced through APEX **REST Data Source** and added to the local tables via a PLSQL trigger.

*Sample JSON response*

```
[
  {
    "order_id": "ZCHI8-N9Zm-VJ1o",
    "order_number": 89653,
    "order_date": "2023-01-01",
    "store_id": 1,
    "full_name": "Amalee Planque",
    "email": "aplanque0@shinystat.com",
    "city": "Houston",
    "state": "Texas",
    "zip_code": "77040",
    "credit_card": "5048378382993155",
    "order_items": [
      {
        "line_number": 1,
        "product_id": 4,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 3919.8
      },
      {
        "line_number": 2,
        "product_id": 6,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 3089.36
      },
      {
        "line_number": 3,
        "product_id": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 3474.4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "order_id": "XZnQx-PwYR-zWy2",
    "order_number": 37946,
    "order_date": "2022-01-29",
    "store_id": 2,
    "full_name": "Marillin Gadie",
    "email": "mgadie1@comsenz.com",
    "city": "Cleveland",
    "state": "Ohio",
    "zip_code": "44191",
    "credit_card": "5108757233070957",
    "order_items": [
      {
        "line_number": 1,
        "product_id": 5,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 3184.37
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

*Trigger to insert the `order_items` to the `ORDER_ITEMS` table*

```
create or replace trigger "TR_MAINTAIN_LINES"
AFTER
insert or update or delete on "ORDERS_LOCAL"
for each row
begin
    if inserting or updating then
        if updating then
          delete ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
          where order_id = :old.order_id;
        end if;
        insert into ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL ( order_id, line_id, line_number, product_id, quantity, price) 
        ( select :new.order_id,
                 seq_line_id.nextval,
                 j.line_number,
                 j.product_id,
                 j.quantity,
                 j.price
            from json_table( 
                     :new.order_items,
                     '$[*]' columns (
                         line_id for ordinality,
                         line_number number path '$.line_number',
                         product_id  number path '$.product_id',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    number        path '$.price' ) ) j );
    elsif deleting then
        delete ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
        where order_id = :old.order_id;
    end if;
end;
```

The `ORDERS` table contains all the order fields (`order_id`, `order_number`, etc.) It also contains `order_items` as a JSON array. (which gets extracted into the `ORDER_ITEMS` table by the trigger)

*`ORDERS` table*
[image]

*`ORDERS` table data*
[image]

The `ORDER_ITEMS` table contains all the order item fields (`line_number`, `quantity`, `price`). It also contains the `order_id` to reference which order the line item is referring to.

*`ORDER_ITEMS` table*
[image]

*`ORDER_ITEMS` table data*
[image]

I need to add an `ORDER_TAX` column to the `ORDERS` table. In which:

- Grabs the `order_items` from the `ORDER_ITEMS` table which has the same `order_id`.
- Adds all the `price` columns to get the total.
- Multiply the total by 0.15 to simulate the estimated sales tax
- Insert the 'sales tax' into the `ORDER_TAX` column in the `ORDERS` table.

I've created the `ORDER_TAX` column. I think I need to create a new trigger for this but I'm not quite sure how to code this out. I also need to create an `ORDER_TOTAL` column to the `ORDERS` table but I think I can figure that out once someone helps me with this initial question.

**-----------UPDATE--------------**

Per Koen's comment, it seems I need to actually create a view for this instead of a trigger.

The SQL query below returns the expected results

```
select ORDER_ID, SUM(PRICE) * 0.15 AS ORDER_TAX
from ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
GROUP BY ORDER_ID
```

How do I create a view so it inserts the value into the `ORDERS` table, `ORDER_TAX` column?

[image]

Comment: Don't implement this using a trigger. Instead create a view that has the ORDER_ID and calculates the order_tax for the order. The data will always be accurate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I've updated my question. Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: May I suggest you read up on views and give it a try yourself first. A view doesn't "inserts values" as you state, it is an a validated and named SQL query that is stored in the database. You're the developer of this application, you have to figure out what the best architecture is for it. Probably a view will work for this purpose, maybe it doesn't - only you can decide that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it really helped :) and I learned alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Koen's comment, I've been able to figure this out.

Go to **Object Browser** Create View

```
select 
    ORDERS_LOCAL.*,
    A2.TAX,
    A2.SUBTOTAL,
    A2.TOTAL
from ORDERS_LOCAL
inner join (
    select 
        ORDER_ID,
        cast(sum(price) *0.15 as decimal(10,2)) as tax,
        sum(price) as subtotal,
        cast(sum(price) *1.15 as decimal(10,2)) as total
    from ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
    group by ORDER_ID
) A2
ON ORDERS_LOCAL.ORDER_ID=A2.ORDER_ID;
```

I then created a **Master Detail** report with the view as the source.

[image]