# Oracle Apex - REST data source - nested JSON array - trigger two tables - delete function error ORA-04091

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

This question is a follow up to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75219903/oracle-apex-rest-data-source-nested-json-array-trigger-two-tables-update).

I have an app with a REST Data Source taking in JSON responses from an API. There are two tables `ORDERS` and `ORDER_ITEMS`. The `ORDERS` table contains a column `ORDER_ITEMS` which is a *JSON Document* type.

I created a trigger on my `ORDERS` table which runs `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE` on my `ORDERS` table, and which maintains the `ORDER_ITEMS` table (Extracts the JSON array from the `ORDERS` table `ORDER_ITEMS` column and inserts into `ORDER_ITEMS` table and each column).

```
create or replace trigger "TR_MAINTAIN_LINES"
AFTER
insert or update or delete on "ORDERS_LOCAL"
for each row
begin
    if inserting or updating then
        if updating then
          delete ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
          where order_id = :old.order_id;
        end if;
        insert into ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL ( order_id, line_id, line_number, product_id, quantity, price) 
        ( select :new.order_id,
                 seq_line_id.nextval,
                 j.line_number,
                 j.product_id,
                 j.quantity,
                 j.price
            from json_table( 
                     :new.order_items,
                     '$[*]' columns (
                         line_id for ordinality,
                         line_number number path '$.line_number',
                         product_id  number path '$.product_id',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    number        path '$.price' ) ) j );
    elsif deleting then
        delete ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
        where order_id = :old.order_id;
    end if;
end;
```

The trigger works for `AFTER INSERT` and `UPDATE`. However, when I try to `DELETE` a row from the `ORDERS` table, I receive an error. `error ORA-04091: table WKSP_DEMO.ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`

But deleting a row from the `ORDER_ITEMS` table works as expected.

- `ORDERS` table
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsqRW.png)
- `ORDERS` table data
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuK7M.png)
- `ORDER_ITEMS` table
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10XkG.png)
- `ORDER_ITEMS` table data
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4TrI.png)
- Triggers [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12kU8.png)
- `BI_ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL` trigger

```
create or replace trigger "BI_ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL"   
  before insert on "ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."LINE_ID" is null then 
    select "ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."LINE_ID" from sys.dual; 
  end if; 
end;
```

- Error Message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoLLC.png)

**---- UPDATE ------**

So I took out the delete portion of the trigger and both `ORDER` and `ORDER_LINES` table rows get deleted as expected.

```
create or replace trigger "TR_MAINTAIN_LINES"
AFTER
insert or update on "ORDERS_LOCAL"
for each row
begin
    if inserting or updating then
        if updating then
          delete ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
          where order_id = :old.order_id;
        end if;
        insert into ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL ( order_id, line_id, line_number, product_id, quantity, price) 
        ( select :new.order_id,
                 seq_line_id.nextval,
                 j.line_number,
                 j.product_id,
                 j.quantity,
                 j.price
            from json_table( 
                     :new.order_items,
                     '$[*]' columns (
                         line_id for ordinality,
                         line_number number path '$.line_number',
                         product_id  number path '$.product_id',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    number        path '$.price' ) ) j );

    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Is there a trigger on order_items_local ?

Comment: This is the only trigger that I have

Comment: `DELETING` a row in `ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL` table works as expected but I'm not able to delete a row in `ORDERS` table

Comment: The error indicates that ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL is mutating. That would happen if there is a select on that table in a trigger on the same table. It's unlikely to see that error in a trigger on another table. Are you sure the error is thrown in *that* trigger ? The error message should indicate in which trigger it is raised.

Comment: The attached image shows there is a trigger BI_ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL. What is the source of that trigger ?

Comment: I believe it's part of the `TR_MAINTAIN_LINES` trigger. I didn't create this manually. I've added the code to the bottom of the question. As well as the error message I'm receiving

Comment: I don't see an immediate solution. I'm out the rest of the day so won't be able to reply

Comment: As Koen was correctly stating, this error happens if you have a trigger on one table, which (in its code) selects rows from the same table. One more question: 1. Is there a ON DELETE CASCADE foreign key between your ORDER_LOCAL and ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL table?

Comment: Hi Carsten, ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL table does have an `ON DELETE CASCADE ` foreign key. `ALTER TABLE  "ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL" ADD CONSTRAINT "ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL_FK_ORDER_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("ORDER_ID")
   REFERENCES  "ORDERS_LOCAL" ("ORDER_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE`

Comment: So I took out the delete portion of the trigger and it seems to work now. I've updated the question to show the updated trigger. It works but do you see anything potentially wrong with doing this?

Comment: No this should be fine, if there is a delete from ```ORDERS_LOCAL```, the database will delete the child row because of ```ON DELETE CASCADE``` clause in the foreign key definition.

Answer (score 0):

you have a conflict between the ON DELETE CASCADE clause and your trigger logic. In the DELETE case, both attempt to delete the child rows. You can ...

- remove the DELETE section from your trigger and let the ON DELETE CASCADE clause do the job
- remove the ON DELETE CASCADE clause from your foreign key.

I think, I'd recommend the second option, so that all that logic is in one place, i.e. your trigger.