# Oracle Apex 22.21 - REST data source - trigger to convert string to_number and add into a column

Tags: oracle-apex

This question is a follow up to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192510/oracle-apex-rest-data-source-nested-json-array-sync-two-tables-where-to).

I have an app with a REST Data Source taking in JSON responses from an API. There are two tables ORDERS and LINES. The ORDERS table contains a column LINES which is a JSON Document type.

I created a trigger on my ORDERS table which runs `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE` on my ORDERS table, and which maintains the LINES table (Extracts the JSON array from the ORDERS table ORDER_ITEMS column and inserts into ORDER_ITEMS table and each column).

```
SAMPLE JSON RESPONSE FROM API
[ {
  "order_number": "so1223",
  "order_date": "2022-07-01",
  "full_name": "Carny Coulter",
  "email": "ccoulter2@ovh.net",
  "credit_card": "3545556133694494",
  "city": "Myhiya",
  "state": "CA",
  "zip_code": "12345",
  "lines": [
    {
      "product": "Beans - Fava, Canned",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": $1.99
    },
    {
      "product": "Edible Flower - Mixed",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": $1.50
    }
  ]
},
{
  "order_number": "so2244",
  "order_date": "2022-12-28",
  "full_name": "Liam Shawcross",
  "email": "lshawcross5@exblog.jp",
  "credit_card": "6331104669953298",
  "city": "Humaitá",
  "state": "NY",
  "zip_code": "98670",
  "lines": [
    {
      "order_id": 5,
      "product": "Beans - Green",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": $4.33
    },
    {
      "order_id": 1,
      "product": "Grapefruit - Pink",
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": $5.00
    }
  ]
},
]
```

```
create or replace trigger "TR_MAINTAIN_LINES"
AFTER
insert or update on "ORDERS"
for each row
begin
    if inserting or updating then
        if updating then
          delete LINES
          where order_number = :old.order_number;
        end if;
        insert into LINES ( order_number, product, quantity, price, item_image) 
        ( select :new.order_number,
                 j.product,
                 j.quantity,
                 j.price,
                 j.item_image
            from json_table( 
                     :new.lines,
                     '$[*]' columns (
                         product  varchar2(4000) path '$.product',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    varchar2(4000) path '$.price', 
                         item_image varchar2(4000) path '$.item_image' ) ) j );
    end if;
end;
```

So this works as expected right now. However, the PRICE column is a varchar type due to the '$' in the JSON response. (Ex: $1.99). I'm able to change this to a number type in a view by using `TO_NUMBER(price,'$999,999,999.99')`.

**How can I do this within the trigger?**

- Have the trigger after insert or update, convert the PRICE column (varchar) to a another column TOTAL_PRICE (number).
- I also want to add another column UNIT_PRICE which takes TOTAL_PRICE/QUANTITY.

Are these possible within the given trigger or would I have to create a separate trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### For column TOTAL_PRICE

Yes this can be done in the trigger. Add the column to the lines table and modify the insert statement

```
...
       insert into LINES ( order_number, product, quantity, price, total_price, item_image) 
        ( select :new.order_number,
                 j.product,
                 j.quantity,
                 j.price,
                 TO_NUMBER(j.price,'$999.99'),
                 j.item_image
            from json_table( 
                     :new.lines,
                     '$[*]' columns (
                         product  varchar2(4000) path '$.product',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    varchar2(4000) path '$.price', 
                         item_image varchar2(4000) path '$.item_image' ) ) j );
...
```

###### For column UNIT_PRICE

This can be done in the trigger as well but... it makes more sense to add a "virtual column" here since unit price is always TOTAL_PRICE/QUANTITY. A virtual column cannot be updated/inserted, only selected - the value is always  up to date

```
alter table lines add unit_price number generated always as ( total_price / quantity ) virtual;
```